In pine script the code that ı copy from someone else is give an error but original code has not an error
London = time(timeframe.period, Londont)
US = time(timeframe.period, USt)
Asia = time(timeframe.period, Asiat)

var clondonhigh = 0.0
var clondonlow = close
var londontime = time
var flondonhigh = 0.0
var flondonlow = 0.0
var flondonopen = 0.0

var onelondonfalse = false
if London
    if high > clondonhigh
        clondonhigh := high
        clondonhigh
    if low < clondonlow
        clondonlow := low
        clondonlow
    if onelondonfalse
        londontime := time
        flondonopen := open
        flondonopen
    flondonhigh := clondonhigh
    flondonlow := clondonlow
    onelondonfalse := false
    onelondonfalse
else
    if onelondonfalse == false
        flondonhigh := clondonhigh
        flondonlow := clondonlow
        flondonlow
    onelondonfalse := true

    clondonhigh := 0.0
    clondonlow := close
    clondonlow

//////////////////////////////////
var cushigh = 0.0
var cuslow = close
var ustime = time
var fushigh = 0.0
var fuslow = 0.0
var fusopen = 0.0

var oneusfalse = false
if US
    if high > cushigh
        cushigh := high
        cushigh
    if low < cuslow
        cuslow := low
        cuslow
    if oneusfalse
        ustime := time
        fusopen := open
        fusopen
    fushigh := cushigh
    fuslow := cuslow
    oneusfalse := false
    oneusfalse
else
    if oneusfalse == false
        fushigh := cushigh
        fuslow := cuslow
        fuslow
    oneusfalse := true

    cushigh := 0.0
    cuslow := close
    cuslow

//////////////////////////////////
var casiahigh = 0.0
var casialow = close
var asiatime = time
var fasiahigh = 0.0
var fasialow = 0.0
var fasiaopen = 0.0

var oneasiafalse = false
if Asia
    if high > casiahigh
        casiahigh := high
        casiahigh
    if low < casialow
        casialow := low
        casialow
    if oneasiafalse
        asiatime := time
        fasiaopen := open
        fasiaopen
    fasiahigh := casiahigh
    fasialow := casialow
    oneasiafalse := false
    oneasiafalse
else
    if oneasiafalse == false
        fasiahigh := casiahigh
        fasialow := casialow
        fasialow
    oneasiafalse := true

    casiahigh := 0.0
    casialow := close
    casialow

the code is here. In original code there is no error but when ı copy the code completely its give an error
"The condition of the if statement must evaluate to a 'bool' value.
London (user-defined variable)
type series int"
like this in "if Asia", "if Us" and if London" lines what is the problem in here and how can i solve it
ı try to add boolean expression in if lines like
if London == londontime
there is no error in code but that time my indicator cant stand on the graph

It is not an error but a warning.
time() returns series int and you are using it as if it was bool in your if checks.
Just cast them to bool and it will be good.
London = bool(time(timeframe.period, Londont))
US = bool(time(timeframe.period, USt))
Asia = bool(time(timeframe.period, Asiat))

